# Extra static background with correct scrollable grid view on top of it

Tags: android, android-fragments, gridview, android-adapter

I have an image adapter in a fragment I have the following code in Image Adapter :

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(185, 185));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
    };
}
```

and onCreateView for the fragment is given below:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View rootview=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movies, container, false);;

        GridView gridview = (GridView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.moviesgrid);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity()));

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + position,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return rootview;
}
```

Now when I run the project it shows the scrollable grid as desired but it also shows a static grid in the backgreound of the same images that are shown in the scrollable grid. Could you please point out where that extra background is coming from??

**Edit 1 for adding XML files:**

Please check below the XML for Main Activity :

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.example.android.popularmovies.PopularMoviesFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_movies"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Please check below the XML for Fragment :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$PPopularMoviesFragment"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_main">
    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/moviesgrid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:columnWidth="145dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

I have attached the screenshot of the problem I am facing. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Could you upload your xml files please?

Comment: @RAS : Here are the XML for the layouts of Main Activity and Frament.